# Highmaps - Political borders

Tags: highcharts, maps, gis, highmaps

I've been working on this project for a few months. 
http://codenamedev.com/proofs/GFN11/ecological.html

I'm running into some issues with the maps borders not lining up to the clients data. In the case of disputed borders, or other grey areas where no one seems to agree as to the status of country.  What is the method of overriding the highmaps map data.   I understand they get their data  from  the Natural Earth data library

**for example:** 
Singapore should be its own country (depends who you ask) but HighMaps considers Singapore as part of Malaysia.

French Guiana is part a colony of France.  I have a data set for French Guiana but Highmaps definition of the world thinks it is France. https://goo.gl/CeAK07

I'd like to find a neat way of doing this without having to redraw the world.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can edit maps by QGIS tool.

Ref:
- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps